# problems with local storage and onClick on page refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net, onclick

hello guys i am woking on this app where there are 3 states on a button

first state, this is the default when the web page is openend for the first time

Picture 1:-

[image]

then when you click it, it changes to another image, and sets a timer.

Picture 2:-

[image]

when the timer is over it changes again to another image.

Picture 3:-

[image]

then when u click it again it is changing to picture nr 2 with green outline and start timer again,

I use local storage to make sure I save the timer and the pictures, but my problem is when I refresh the page I turns back to picture number 1, here I would like it to remember what "state" it was in, if it was clicked once I need it to on refresh, remember that I should be "green" like on picture 2 and wait for the timer to end and turn "red" like on picture 3, and if the timer was out and it was red like on picture 3 I need it to remember that also!

I'm REALLY lost, and all new to this, so I hoping for help, maybe and example..

thanks in advance :( :O

here a my html button code:

```
 <img class="toilet" src="~/lib/pictures/toilet.png" style="height:150px;width:150px;" />
```

and here is my javascript:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {


 function aktivereSkift(
 initImagePath = null,
 initNextImagePath = null,
 count = 15
 ) {


 if (initImagePath === null || initNextImagePath === null) {
    return false;
}
$(this).attr("src", initImagePath);

let timer = count * 1000;
let counter = setInterval(timerLS.bind(this, count), 1000);

function timerLS() {
    count = count - 1;

    localStorage.setItem("counter", count); 

    



    if (count <= 0) {    
         
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
        
        
        
    }
}
     setTimeout(() => $(this).attr("src", initNextImagePath), timer);

    localStorage.setItem("nextimagepath", initNextImagePath);

     localStorage.setItem("imagepath", initImagePath);



    }



function loadDefaultValues() {
const initImagePath = localStorage.getItem("imagepath");
const initNextImagePath = localStorage.getItem("nextimagepath");
const counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");

aktivereSkift(initImagePath, initNextImagePath, counter);
    }

  

 loadDefaultValues();

 $(".toilet").on("click", function () {
 aktivereSkift.call(this, '/lib/pictures/toiletBegyndt.png', '/lib/pictures/toiletSlut.png');

 });

 });

 </script>
```

Comment: When will it returns to its initial state "picture 1"?

Comment: it should return to its inital state with some kind of timer, what i want it to do, is return to its inital state lets say 12:00 am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<img class="toilet" src="~/lib/pictures/toilet.png" style="height:150px;width:150px;" data-id="1"/>
<img class="toilet" src="~/lib/pictures/toilet.png" style="height:150px;width:150px;" data-id="2"/>
<img class="toilet" src="~/lib/pictures/toilet.png" style="height:150px;width:150px;" data-id="3"/>
```

JS:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

var objects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects") || "[]");
objects.forEach(function(object, index) {
    if (localStorage.getItem("counter " + object.id) > 0) {
      aktivereSkift(object.imagePath, object.nextImagePath, object.id, localStorage.getItem("counter " + object.id), true);
    } else if (localStorage.getItem("counter " + object.id) == 0) {
      aktivereSkift(object.imagePath, object.nextImagePath, object.id, localStorage.getItem("counter " + object.id), true);
    } else {
      loadDefaultValues();
    }
});

function aktivereSkift(initImagePath = null, initNextImagePath = null, id = 0, count = 15, isRefresh = false) {
  
  if (initImagePath === null || initNextImagePath === null) {
    return false;
  }

  
  isRefresh ? $('.toilet[data-id="'+ id +'"]').attr("src", initImagePath) : $(this).attr("src", initImagePath);

  let timer = count * 1000;

  let counter = setInterval(timerLS.bind(this, count), 1000);
  
  var objects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects") || "[]");
  
  var obj = {id: id, imagePath: initImagePath, nextImagePath: initNextImagePath }
  
  const i = objects.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
  if (i > -1) objects[i] = obj; 
  else objects.push(obj);
  

  localStorage.setItem("objects", JSON.stringify(objects)); 

  function timerLS() {
    count = count - 1;
    
     localStorage.setItem("counter " + id, count < 0 ? 0 : count);

    if (count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
    }
  }

  setTimeout(() => isRefresh ? $('.toilet[data-id="'+ id +'"]').attr("src", initNextImagePath) : $(this).attr("src", initNextImagePath), timer);
  
}



function loadDefaultValues() {
  const initImagePath = localStorage.getItem("imagepath");
  const initNextImagePath = localStorage.getItem("nextimagepath");
  const counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");

  aktivereSkift(initImagePath, initNextImagePath, counter);
}



$(".toilet").on("click", function() {
  aktivereSkift.call(this, '/lib/pictures/toiletBegyndt.png', '/lib/pictures/toiletSlut.png', $(this).attr("data-id"));
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: works perfectly, but i forgot to mention that i have multiple rows, and when i refresh page i only needs to work with some kind of binding, as i does with the first click, as for now with your help, when i refresh page alle rows  if counter > 0 turns "green" i need to bind it, is that possible?

Comment: works perfectly, but i forgot to mention that i have multiple rows, and when i refresh page i only needs to work with some kind of binding, as i does with the first click, as for now with your help, when i refresh page alle rows  if counter > 0 turns "green" i need to bind it so it only turns green on the one where the timer is still going and on the ones where the timer is out, it should be red, is that possible?

Comment: I have updated the code according to your requirement. I've added a data-id attribute on the image tag to uniquely identify it, created an array of objects to store each image details, created a separate counter for each image, and concatenate them with the image id to get their counter value.

Comment: i really appreciate the work you have done, and i can see where it is going, but unfortunately if i use that html code u have editet, i have 3 pictures wher i only need one, and i still refreshes the others rows in my foreach loop when i activate with first click like on picture 2, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: i have posted my foreach code loop in the thread maybe there is something in there is has not shared, maybe it is important for me to explain what my problem is, sry for that if that is the case

Comment: i made it work, thank you with your help i just created a dynamic variable wich increases by 1 for every time the foreach loop has done its work, that gives each picture a uniqe ID.. i love you!!! :D :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Local storage survives page refresh. you don't need a backend server for this, it can be done using `JS`.
Have a method that sets up the content panel

```
function loadContent(state){
// get state as parameter and show buttons accordingly
}
```

on your `$(document).ready` check is local storage holds those values (`localStorage.getItem()`) that you need. if it does pass those if not pass initial setting

Answer (score 0):

this i the code i have now, and it still refreshes other rows in my foreach loop

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
    {







        <tr>

            <td>
                <img src="@String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(item.billede))" style="width:150px;height:150px; border-radius:15px;" />

            </td>



            <td>


                <div>


                    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                    <img class="toilet" src="~/lib/pictures/toilet.png" style="height:150px;width:150px;" data-id="1" />
                    <img class="toilet" src="~/lib/pictures/toilet.png" style="height:150px;width:150px;" data-id="2" />
                    <img class="toilet" src="~/lib/pictures/toilet.png" style="height:150px;width:150px;" data-id="3" />






                </div>

            </td>

            <td>

                <div>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="Behov" data-placement="bottom" title="Behov" data-content="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.behov)"><input type="image" src="~/lib/pictures/behov.png" style="height:150px;width:150px" /></a>
                </div>


            </td>

            <td>

                <div>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="Sove" data-placement="bottom" title="Søvnbehov" data-content="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sove)"><input type="image" src="~/lib/pictures/sove.png" style="height:150px;width:150px" /></a>
                </div>


            </td>

            <td>


                <div>
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="Div" data-placement="bottom" title="Diverse" data-content="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.div)"><input type="image" src="~/lib/pictures/diverse.png" style="height:150px;width:150px" /></a>
                </div>


            </td>

            <td>
                <div>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><input type="image" src="~/lib/pictures/Redigere.png" style="height:150px;width:150px" /></a>

                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div>

                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id"><input type="image" src="~/lib/pictures/slet.png" style="height:150px;width:150px" /></a>


                </div>
            </td>

        </tr>

        <tr><td colspan="7"><h2><center>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.navn)</center></h2></td></tr>













    }

</tbody>
```

```
@section scripts
                {


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var objects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects") || "[]");
        objects.forEach(function (object, Index) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("counter " + object.id) > 0) {
                aktivereSkift(object.imagePath, object.nextImagePath, object.id, localStorage.getItem("counter " + object.id), true);
            } else if (localStorage.getItem("counter " + object.id) == 0) {
                aktivereSkift(object.imagePath, object.nextImagePath, object.id, localStorage.getItem("counter " + object.id), true);
            } else {
                loadDefaultValues();
            }
        });

        function aktivereSkift(initImagePath = null, initNextImagePath = null, id = 0, count = 15, isRefresh = false) {

            if (initImagePath === null || initNextImagePath === null) {
                return false;
            }


            isRefresh ? $('.toilet[data-id="' + id + '"]').attr("src", initImagePath) : $(this).attr("src", initImagePath);

            let timer = count * 1000;

            let counter = setInterval(timerLS.bind(this, count), 1000);

            var objects = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects") || "[]");

            var obj = { id: id, imagePath: initImagePath, nextImagePath: initNextImagePath }

            const i = objects.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
            if (i > -1) objects[i] = obj;
            else objects.push(obj);


            localStorage.setItem("objects", JSON.stringify(objects));

            function timerLS() {
                count = count - 1;

                localStorage.setItem("counter " + id, count < 0 ? 0 : count);

                if (count <= 0) {
                    clearInterval(counter);
                    return;
                }
            }

            setTimeout(() => isRefresh ? $('.toilet[data-id="' + id + '"]').attr("src", initNextImagePath) : $(this).attr("src", initNextImagePath), timer);

        }



        function loadDefaultValues() {
            const initImagePath = localStorage.getItem("imagepath");
            const initNextImagePath = localStorage.getItem("nextimagepath");
            const counter = localStorage.getItem("counter");

            aktivereSkift(initImagePath, initNextImagePath, counter);
        }



        $(".toilet").on("click", function () {
            aktivereSkift.call(this, '/lib/pictures/toiletBegyndt.png', '/lib/pictures/toiletSlut.png', $(this).attr("data-id"));
        });
    });
</script>
```